# Getting and error when I try to call my class template function from main

Tags: c++, class

I'm getting the below error when try to call my function `add()` from the main.

> C:\studies\NMB1231_Question5\main.cpp:25:23: error: no matching function for call to 'Dictionary<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::add(int&, std::__cxx11::string&)'

.h file

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class A,class B>
class Dictionary
{
    public:
        Dictionary();
        void add(A key,  const B &value);
        B find (A key) const;
        void display();
    
    private:
        vector<A> keys;
        vector<B> values;
};
```

.cpp

```cpp
#include "Dictionary.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class A,class B>
Dictionary<A,B>::Dictionary()
{
    //nothing to do, vector member variables are empty on declaration
};

template <class A,class B>
void Dictionary<A,B>::add(A key,  const B &value)
{
    keys.push_back(key);
    values.push_back(value);
}
    
template <class A,class B>
B Dictionary<A,B>::find (A key) const
{
    B value = " ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
        if (key == keys[i])
            value = values[i];
    if (value == " ")
        return "no such key can be found";
    else return value;
}

template <class A,class B>
void Dictionary<A,B>::display()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
        cout << keys[i] << ' ' << values[i] << endl;
    return;
}
```

main

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Dictionary.h"
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dictionary <vector<int>, vector<string > > part1;
    string part;
    int key;
    //add 4 values to the parts dictionary

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a part name and a key to add to the parts dictionary." << endl;
        cout << "Part name: ";
        getline(cin, part);
        cout << "Key for part name: ";
        cin >> key;
        part1.add(key,part);
        cin.get();
    }

    cout << endl;
    part1.display();
    cout << endl;

    //find the part for a key
    cout << "For which key do you want to find the part? ";
    cin >> key;
    cout << "The part for key " << key << " is ";
    cout << part1.find(key) << endl;
    // cout << parts.find(100002);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sneftel The duplicated question is irrelevant to the error in this quesion.

Comment: You wanted std::map instead of std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

In main, you are declaring your `part1` variable as `Dictionary<vector<int>, vector<string>>`. So its `A` template parameter is `vector<int>` and its `B` template parameter is `vector<string>`.

`Dictionary::add()` takes instances of `A` and `B` as parameters. So, in this case, `add()` is expecting a `vector<int>` in its 1st parameter and a `vector<string>` in its 2nd parameter. But main is passing an `int` and a `string` instead. That is why you are getting the error.

You need to declare `part1` as `Dictionary<int, string>` instead.

---

That being said, there are other problems with your code.

- `Dictionary::add()` does not look for an existing `key` before pushing the input into the `vector`s. If the `key` already exists, you should *replace* the existing entry with the new `value`, otherwise push the new `key` and `value`.  By definition, a dictionary should not contain duplicate keys.
- `Dictionary::find()` does not compile when `B` is not `std::string` or `const char*`. Also, if it can't find the specified `key` it should either return a default-constructed `B`, or throw an exception.
- You really should be using `std::(unordered_)map` instead of `std::vector`. Let it handle the `key`/`value` management for you.
- [You can't implement a template class in separate `.h`/`.cpp` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/) (not the way you are trying to do, anyway).

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for you assistance, this was very insightful.

Comment: If I change my declaration of part1 to  Dictionary<int, string>, I now get more errors because my functions are expecting vectors not <int, string>.  I also need to keep using vector because this what is required in the assignment, I'm not allowed to change the data type. Error                                                                                    -  undefined reference to `Dictionary<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Dictionary()'

Comment: @Gladmalete `part1` needs to be `Dictionary<int, string>`, that is the way you coded `main()` to expect, and it just makes sense for a dictionary anyway. As for the `undefined reference` error, that is because [you can't implement a template class in separate `h`/`cpp` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/) (not the way you are trying to do, anyway) .

Comment: moving the function implementation to the header file seems to resolve the error. thank you.